# jQuery Accordion: height problems when using stop() during slideUp/slideDown -is data() a solution?

Tags: jquery

Good evening everyone!

I'm stuck with my selfmade accordion again. I've got an Accordion, with basically looks like this:

```
<dl>
<dt> <a href></a> </dt>
<dd> Text </dd>

<dt> <a href></a> </dt>
<dd> Text </dd>

<dt> <a href></a> </dt>
<dd> Text </dd>

<dt> <a href></a> </dt>
<dd> Text </dd>

<dt> <a href></a> </dt>
<dd> Text </dd>
</dl>
```

When you click on a link, the previously hidden dd right behind the anchor slidesDown (respectively when another dd is visible, this one slidesUp additionaly and if the dd right behind the anchor is visible, it just slidesUp -in other words: theres only one of the Texts open at the same time). It works pretty well, but now I'm stuck with the following Problem:

When you click multiple times, the animations get queued.

My solution was to use .stop() before the animation starts. Basically that works fine, but this cause an new problem: the height of the Element is locked up at the value the animation is stopped and when I call the animation again, it fades only to this height.

I searched the web and there seems to be a solution, which looks like this:

```
$("#elementId").data('origHeight',$("#elementId").height());
```

This should "store" the original height of the Element and with

```
$("#elementId").data('origHeight');
```

you can readout this value. But I don't get where to put this and how it works, if every slide-Element has a different height.

If anyone can help me out with this or can suggest another way, that would totaly make my night and the next few days

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using [the jQuery UI accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)? At least look through the source code, if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm want to get used to jquery, therefor I want to create an accordion for myself. And in fact it works very well besides this one problem -so I'm very, very close to the goal! Don't want to give up now and use a plugin ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.stop(true,true);` ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/stop/))

Comment: In fact I already tried this and it didn't worked out for two reasons: If I doubleclick on a anchor, the animation jumps to the end (and looks very ugly^^) and in addition, there's a function (lets call it cut^^) which is called at the end of the slideDown, and a function with undoes the cut-function, when the slideDown of another anchor is called. These two functions are called simultaneously and only "cut" is executed.

Comment: So to be clear: I don't want the first function to finish, but to stop instantly, cause then the cut-function won't be called and everything is fine. Except the problem with the ne height.

Comment: Did you try `.stop(true)` then? Not adding the second boolean makes that value default to false and doesn't allow the animation to complete. If that doesn't help, maybe if you made a demo of your slider on http://jsfiddle.net/ it would help clarify the problem.

Comment: yes, i've tried .stop(true), but then the problem with the new, wrong height still occurs.